# gawk: How i can print output genrated by gawk command in multiple line on terminal in single line in file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am using gawk command to print column content in file like:

```
gawk '{print $2205764, $2205763}' /home/mohasin/fil1.txt
```

It generates output on terminal with new line:

```
a a
b b
c c
d d
. .
. .
```

I want this output in single row in file, how I can do this?

```
a a b b c c d d......
```

Comment: @hey Guys .. I got Solution.

Comment: awk '{print $2}' < file.txt | paste -s -d ' '

Comment: This question was answered before, I can not find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Set the output record separator (`ORS`) to a space.  By default it's a newline.

You can do this in the `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }' inputfile
```

Or, equivalently, you can do it as a command line argument to `awk`:

```
awk -v ORS=" " '{ print }' inputfile
```

Either of these will join all the lines of `inputfile` into a single line.  (There will be a trailing space.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tr` command to turn your newlines into spaces.

```
gawk '{print $2205764, $2205763}' /home/mohasin/fil1.txt | tr '\n' ' ' > file.txt
```